# Is it possible to use etc/hosts to block a specific part of a whole website

Tags: macos, youtube, websites, hosts

I know how to use etc/hosts to block something such as youtube.com

However, I when I try to use etc/hosts to block something such as: youtube.com/user/TEDtalksDirector

nothing seems to happen. Is it possible to block a specific channel on youtube with etc/hosts instead of the entire site, and if so how is it done?

Here is my etc/hosts file (youtube user is modified):

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
#
127.0.0.1       www.youtube.com/user/TEDtalksDirector
```

Comment: No: [How to block URL with parameter in Windows hosts file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607694/how-to-block-url-with-parameter-in-windows-hosts-file) & [Uniform Resource Identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) - please check the example. The hosts file can only "manipulate" the *host* part of an URL by translating it to different IP-address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You need a web proxy or other filter product that snoops on and processes the URL instead of just the main host.